# Color each column in the angular ui grid differently

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to be able to color each column in the ui-grid with a different color. I want to specify what the color of each column should be. Is there a way to do it currently in the ui grid?

Comment: Yes, this can easily be done using custom templates http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates and some markup with scope variable declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved by using the `cellClass` columnDef property as explained [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef).

`cellClass` can either be a string or a `function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex)` that returns a class name. So, basically when defining your columns do something like this:

```
gridOptions.columnDefs = [{field: 'field1', cellClass: 'yourClass'}];
```

Just be careful when changing background-color since it gets overwritten by cell backgrounds. You should add something like this to your css:

```
.ui-grid-row .ui-grid-cell {
   background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: It used the cellClass property and I have this working now. Thank you for your help.